# How does one reassign variables in an object?

Tags: javascript-objects

For a class I'm taking, I need to reassign an object's properties to "Unknown". Here is the sample problem:

```
//In the function below, "person" will be passed in as an object that represents a person with properties such as name, age, gender, etc.
//Loop through all the properties of the object and set each value equal to "Unknown"
//For example, if "person" is {name: "Dolph L.", age: 33} then the function would return {name: "Unknown", age: "Unknown"}

function describePerson(person) {
    //code here
}
```

If I'm understanding is correctly, it says that I must loop through the object and reassign it's properties to "Unknown". What I've been trying to do is this:

```
function describePerson(person) {
    for (var prop in person) {
       if (prop) {
           return "Unknown";
       }
    } 
}
```

I'm very new to Javascript and could really use some help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var prop in person) {
    if (person.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        person[prop] = "Unknown";
    }
}

return person;
```

You don't want to return in the loop, you want to modify each property of the object using the `=` operator.

The reason behind `hasOwnProperty` is the following.

`person` is an object. The object inherits properties from its [Prototype](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp). You don't care about those inherited properties, so you call `hasOwnProperty` which returns `true` if the property is one you gave it.

Comment: That makes sense. However, when I use your code, this error comes up:Function returned 
undefined
instead of 
{"name":"Unknown","age":"Unknown"}
when passed 
{"name":"Unknown","age":"Unknown"}

Comment: I've tried using person.push(prop), but it tells me that person.push(prop) is not a function.

Comment: @JimmyCarrigan that's because the function needs to return something I suppose. Try returning the object after the loop. Edited answer.

Comment: Still not working. No worries. I'll find a way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JimmyCarrigan What's not working? You're getting an error message, or it's returning the wrong thing?

Comment: I did not see that you had added "return person" before the last curly bracket. It works now! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly, this function loops the properties and changes them to the variable prop, which has a value of "Unknown". Rather than go in and change every property's value, this acts  as a blanket statement that executes for the entire object. Is that the correct way to look at this function?

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding your explanation. The code I posted loops through the properties of the object. For each property it checks if it's a property of the Prototype (read the link I attached; prototypes aren't a beginner concept, so it might be easier to ignore those for the time being). In fact, in your case it will probably work without the `if` statement. It then assigns the string "Unknown" to the property, effectively overwriting its original value (e.g. `name: "abc"` becomes `name: "Unknown"`).

Comment: The answer worked perfectly. I didn't quite understand before, but after reading your explanation again, I feel I have a better grasp of it.